# How to convert Base64 string to image, then bind it to GridView in a Metro Style App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have collection of products from web service, I preview this product in Grid View, but I get the images of the products as Base64 strings. How can I convert it to images and bind it to the images in the Grid View?

Any piece of code that will help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF/Metro/Silverlight, Image is a UI control. Its source is set to BitmapSource. BitmapSource is a data structure to hold image data.

Following is the code to retrieve BitmapImage from byte array.

```
public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource ( stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        return image;
    }
```

Note that stream.AsRandomAccessStream is not available in API It is an extension method. I found it from response of  [IDWMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435224/idwmaster) to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669311/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-system-io-stream-to-a-windows-storage-streams-irando)

Following is the code for extension method

```
 public static class MicrosoftStreamExtensions
    {
        public static IRandomAccessStream AsRandomAccessStream(this Stream stream)
        {
            return new RandomStream(stream);
        }
    }
    class RandomStream : IRandomAccessStream
    {
        Stream internstream;
        public RandomStream(Stream underlyingstream)
        {
            internstream = underlyingstream;
        }
        public IInputStream GetInputStreamAt(ulong position)
        {
            internstream.Position = (long)position;
            return internstream.AsInputStream();
        }

        public IOutputStream GetOutputStreamAt(ulong position)
        {
            internstream.Position = (long)position;
            return internstream.AsOutputStream();
        }

        public ulong Size
        {
            get
            {
                return (ulong)internstream.Length;
            }
            set
            {
                internstream.SetLength((long)value);
            }
        }

        public bool CanRead
        {
            get { return internstream.CanRead; }
        }

        public bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return internstream.CanWrite; }
        }

        public IRandomAccessStream CloneStream()
        {
            //HACK, this is not clone, proper implementation is required, returned object will share same internal stream
            return new RandomStream(this.internstream);
        }

        public ulong Position
        {
            get { return (ulong)internstream.Position; }
        }

        public void Seek(ulong position)
        {
            internstream.Seek((long)position, SeekOrigin.Current);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            internstream.Dispose();
        }

        public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer buffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<bool> FlushAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress<uint, uint> WriteAsync(IBuffer buffer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Last 3 methods are not implemented

I have not tested but above should work in principal (may be after some refinement).

Comment: i am putting the updated code, just clicked ImplementInterface, and provided default values. Code is compiling, and running. can you share sample data, so that i can test the output.

Comment: I got NotImplementedException on Random.ReadAsync when trying execute AsRandomAccessStream.

Comment: Without ReadAsync implementation this is useless.

Comment: @Mike, i had not implemented all the methods. But there should not be much issue implementing it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to implement it. Without this method it just don't work. It was no sense to implement all other staff without this key method.

Answer (score 5):

This seem to work for me:

```
    public static BitmapImage Base64StringToBitmap(string source)
    {
        var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
        var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);
        dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
        dataWriter.StoreAsync();
        ims.Seek(0);
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(ims);
        return img;
    }
```

Note I don't await anything, img.SetSource should take care of delayed load.

Comment: This ended up doing the trick for me as well.  I dumped it into a converter, so now I just data bind to the base64 string and use the converter to do the grunt work.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

below is the method that binds a `Base64String` to an `Image` control

1. convert the string to byte[] as follows

   ```
   byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(thebase64string);
   ```
2. pass the byte[] and the Image control to which you want to bind the Image to.

   ```
   public async void SetImageFromByteArray(byte[] data, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image)
   {
       InMemoryRandomAccessStream raStream =
           new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

       DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(raStream);

       // Write the bytes to the stream
       writer.WriteBytes(data);

       // Store the bytes to the MemoryStream
       await writer.StoreAsync();

       await writer.FlushAsync();

       // Detach from the Memory stream so we don't close it
       writer.DetachStream();

       raStream.Seek(0);

       BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
       bitMapImage.SetSource(raStream);

       image.Source = bitMapImage;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(encodedDataAsBytes.Length);
stream.Write(encodedDataAsBytes, 0, encodedDataAsBytes.Length);
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

I haven't worked with metro, so I can't help with binding to grid..
Best regards.

Comment: are you sure it will work in Metro. Image is a control (in Metro/WPF/Silverlight), not GDI+ System.Windows.Drawing.Image

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay ,but it will not work ,because IMAGE in metro different to IMAGE in GDI ,so have different method