# retrieving data audio from a httpResponse in metro app

Tags: c#, stream, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, httpresponse

I access a web service by HttpClient, and get a response that is supposed to contain a audio data (it is a TTS web service called Voice RSS).

I proceed this way :

```
response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://api.voicerss.org?key=97a912d2574c4538afbf0919ad1f5402&hl=fr-fr&src=hello");
```

Then i take the content of the response :

```
content = response.Content;

stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

result = stream.Result;
```

Then I really hesitate for the rest : I saw in many forums that I should use a MediaElement and set its source to the stream then call the "play" method, but it doesn't work for me.  Others say that I should create a StreamReader to be able to read the stream ...

My goal is to play the sound contained in the response (which can be mp3 , wav etc..).

I don't know if I have to create a MediaElement , an IRandomAccessStream , a IIOStream , or anything else.

I am so confused because I've never found the same issue i'm having.

If you could please help me.

Thanks in advance.

--

Meima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog post:
[How to Convert byte Array to IRandomAccessStream](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/)

He implemented a `class MemoryRandomAccessStream : IRandomAccessStream`

So you can use it, here is my working code:

```
private async void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://api.voicerss.org?key=97a912d2574c4538afbf0919ad1f5402&hl=fr-fr&src=hello");
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    ME.SetSource(new MemoryRandomAccessStream(content), "");
    ME.Play();
}
```

where `ME` is the `MediaElement` in the XAML code:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="ME" ../>
```

PS. After some more search, I found that [a BCL developer said that an extension method will be added in Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355332/71312) so that you can do

```
ME.SetSource(content.AsRandomAccessStream(), "");
```

Comment: Hello! You just have made my day !!!! Thanks alot , now it works :) I will upgrade to Windows 8.1 soon , I hope they will add that extension as for other features (like speech synthetiser wich is missing for now)