# Convert Stream to IRandomAccessStream

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need to convert a `Stream` into an `IRandomAccessStream` (in order to create a `BitmapDecoder`). I tried casting and searching for built-in methods for that in `BitmapDecoder` but couldn't find any.

So how do I do that?

Comment: can you show what code you have or have tried ..this should not be that difficult but it would be nice to see what you have written code wise to see where you have went wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert a System.IO.Stream to a Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669311/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-system-io-stream-to-a-windows-storage-streams-irando)

Comment: @ispiro Your post is a bit old. This `MSDN` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-convert-between-dotnet-streams-and-winrt-streams) should also help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is an extension method for that:

```
Stream stream = GetSomeStream();
IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = stream.AsRandomAccessStream();
```

Just make sure that you have `using System.IO` at the top of your code file.

Comment: Perfect. (Can't accept yet.) I can't believe I didn't see that when searching Intellisense!

Comment: Yippie-ki-yeah!! Couldn't find anywhere. Thx

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Basic Method like this...

```
Dim inputfile As Streams.IRandomAccessStream = System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream(stm)
```

Comment: Could you please add some more information, please?