# How to get byte array from SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

Hi I need help of how to get the byte array from a `SoftwareBitmap` in C# UWP, so that I can send it via TCP socket.

I also have access to a "VideoFrame previewFrame" object which is where I get the `SoftwareBitmap` from.

I have seen online to do something like the following, however UWP does not support the `wb.SaveJpeg(...)`. Unless I am missing something?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myimage);
wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myimage.PixelWidth, myimage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
byte [] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Any help, or pointers in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Andy

Comment: This question has nothing to do with TCP, focus on your real problem "How do I get a byte array from a `SoftwareBitmapSource` in uwp", leave the TCP stuff off for now.

Comment: Ok then, can you please show me how to get a byte array from a SoftwareBitmapSource in uwp?

Comment: I meant [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34291291/edit) and update it with a more focused question (also I don't do uwp so I don't know the answer).

Answer (score 9):

Sure, you can access an ***encoded*** `byte[]` array from a `SoftwareBitmap`.

See this example, extracting a jpeg-encoded `byte[]`:

```
// includes BitmapEncoder, which defines some static encoder IDs
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;


private async void PlayWithData(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap)
{
    // get encoded jpeg bytes
    var data = await EncodedBytes(softwareBitmap, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);

    // todo: save the bytes to a DB, etc
}

private async Task<byte[]> EncodedBytes(SoftwareBitmap soft, Guid encoderId)
{
    byte[] array = null;

    // First: Use an encoder to copy from SoftwareBitmap to an in-mem stream (FlushAsync)
    // Next:  Use ReadAsync on the in-mem stream to get byte[] array

    using (var ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, ms);
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(soft);

        try
        {
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ){ return new byte[0]; }

        array = new byte[ms.Size];
        await ms.ReadAsync(array.AsBuffer(), (uint)ms.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Why is the answer which is supposed to be correct (this one) buried down at the last, whereas a completely irrelevant code is currently highest voted!

Answer (score 5):

to get byte array from SoftwareBitmap you can use "SoftwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer"

But, first you need:

using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

because of method AsBuffer() to byte[]

...

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(ImageFilePath);
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read),
                                           memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
  {
  // Open a Stream and decode a JPG image
  BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
  var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

  byte [] imageBytes = new byte[4*decoder.PixelWidth*decoder.PixelHeight];
  softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(imageBytes.AsBuffer());
  //...  now you can use the imageBytes[]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding context to your code. Also, Please double check the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 4):

as far I know you cant do it. but you can work with SoftwareBitmap. see examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244351.aspx (SoftwareBitmap is private field of SoftwareBitmapSource.. .just read it via reflection... maybe this is totally wrong  suggestion)

```
private async void SaveSoftwareBitmapToFile(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, StorageFile outputFile)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        // Create an encoder with the desired format
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);

        // Set the software bitmap
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);

        // Set additional encoding parameters, if needed
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 320;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 240;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;
        encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = true;

        try
        {
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            switch (err.HResult)
            {
                case unchecked((int)0x88982F81): //WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION
                                                 // If the encoder does not support writing a thumbnail, then try again
                                                 // but disable thumbnail generation.
                    encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw;
            }
        }

        if (encoder.IsThumbnailGenerated == false)
        {
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I have worked out I have access to the SoftwareBitmap, however I still don't see how I can get a byte array from it?
In the example you show above, I don't see where the byte array can be got from?

Comment: using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))    example write bytestream to file. you should use mem stream as buffer or direct output to socket/wcf

Comment: However I am not opening the image from a file, "StorageFile outputFile".

I am getting the SoftwareBitmap from a VideoFrame.
So how can I open a stream from a VideoFrame instead?

Comment: this code save  SoftwareBitmap  to file. softwarebitmap transformed to stream with encoder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226212.aspx .  you can use any IRandomAccessStream stream  . see here how to convert to io streams: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669311/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-system-io-stream-to-a-windows-storage-streams-irando

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My understanding is that the BitmapEncoder needs initialized with a IRandomAccessStream. However how do I get the stream from a SoftwareBitmap?

Comment: You create and pass in a [`InMemoryRandomAccessStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx), once the method has processed it you can read out from that stream and get the bytes it generated.

Comment: Andy there are 2 types of stream input and output :) my example about output stream. exactly what you need.  Encoder will write data to stream.  as  Scott Chamberlain  told: use InMemoryRandomAccessStream..

Comment: You should not rethrow error using `throw err;`, because it overwrites stacktrace.  Use `throw;` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [Get Preview Frame](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/) UWP camera sample gets a camera frame as a `SoftwareBitmap` and manipulates the pixels (in-place) on it through an array, and can save it as a JPEG afterwards. If I understood your question correctly, all the code you need should be there.

Basically, this should be most of it (including some of the camera code):

```
private async Task GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync()
{
    // Get information about the preview
    var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

    // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame
    var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);

    // Capture the preview frame
    using (var currentFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
    {
        // Collect the resulting frame
        SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

        // Add a simple green filter effect to the SoftwareBitmap
        EditPixels(previewFrame);
    }
}

private unsafe void EditPixels(SoftwareBitmap bitmap)
{
    // Effect is hard-coded to operate on BGRA8 format only
    if (bitmap.BitmapPixelFormat == BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8)
    {
        // In BGRA8 format, each pixel is defined by 4 bytes
        const int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;

        using (var buffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
        {
            // Get a pointer to the pixel buffer
            byte* data;
            uint capacity;
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out data, out capacity);

            // Get information about the BitmapBuffer
            var desc = buffer.GetPlaneDescription(0);

            // Iterate over all pixels
            for (uint row = 0; row < desc.Height; row++)
            {
                for (uint col = 0; col < desc.Width; col++)
                {
                    // Index of the current pixel in the buffer (defined by the next 4 bytes, BGRA8)
                    var currPixel = desc.StartIndex + desc.Stride * row + BYTES_PER_PIXEL * col;

                    // Read the current pixel information into b,g,r channels (leave out alpha channel)
                    var b = data[currPixel + 0]; // Blue
                    var g = data[currPixel + 1]; // Green
                    var r = data[currPixel + 2]; // Red

                    // Boost the green channel, leave the other two untouched
                    data[currPixel + 0] = b;
                    data[currPixel + 1] = (byte)Math.Min(g + 80, 255);
                    data[currPixel + 2] = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And declare this outside your class to enable the `GetBuffer` method:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("5b0d3235-4dba-4d44-865e-8f1d0e4fd04d")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
{
    void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
}
```

And of course, your project will have to allow unsafe code for all of this to work.

Finally, this is how you can save a `SoftwareBitmap` to JPEG file:

```
private static async Task SaveSoftwareBitmapAsync(SoftwareBitmap bitmap, StorageFile file)
{
    using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, outputStream);

        // Grab the data from the SoftwareBitmap
        encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(bitmap);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```